# How to disallow user from clicking entry box but still use it with buttons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, widget

So I have this calculator program that I made. I've binded some keyboard buttons and made buttons for the numbers and math operations and stuff. This is all I want the user to be able to do, I don't the user to be able to click on the entry box and manually type in letters or type in his math equation, plus if you manually type a number into the entry box (like 9 for example), that number will print out to the entry box twice and that is because I've already binded that number. So there's just another reason why I need to know how to dissallow the user from manually accessing the entry box.

Comment: So, why do you use an entry widget and not a label?

Comment: The Entry widget has a documented `state` attribute; have you tried setting it to `"disabled"`?

Comment: that is not what I want though because thate will disable the buttons and binds too

Comment: So, what you're really saying is you want a normal entry that only allows specific keys to be pressed? The better solution would be to remove the binds and use input validation instead. Are you interested in that as a solution?

Comment: not really that defeats the whole purpose of haveing the buttons and binds work and not user input because that will really decrease error

Comment: Using input validation in no way affects the "buttons and binds", other than to perhaps not make it necessary to have any custom bindings. This is a classic X/Y question: you have problem X and think Y is the solution so you ask about Y. If you ask about X -- the actual problem you are trying to solve -- you might get better answers.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the advice. I see what you're saying and I think I know what question I'm going to ask.